# Is it possible to detect if an app (Android/iOS) is used in a useragent string?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, user-agent

When an Ajax call (from webapp, Android and iOS apps) is made to our server we log the user agent string.
Is it possible to detect if an app (Android/iOS) is used in a useragent string?